# Find an element with a class without library or getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

This is problem I was asked and am wondering how to do or whether it's a trick question. I've only been working with JavaScript for a short while, so I'm not too sure.

Assume you have a web page with lots of content. **Without using any library or getElementsByClassName**, traverse the DOM and find all elements which have a particular class name.

Sample HTML

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class='myTarget'>
             Target exists here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr> <td class='myTarget'> Target exists here </td> </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div>
       <span class='myTarget notSameAsTarget'>Stuff<span>
    </div>

</body>
```

My first thought is that this should be a recursive function and should start at the root `document.documentElement`

JS:

```
var root = document.documentElement;
var targetClass = 'myTarget';
var elementsWithTargetClass = []; // store in array

function traverse(element, targetClassName){
    // get class of current element
    var currentClass = element.className;

    // add to array if class matches
    if(currentClass.trim() === targetClassName)
        elementsWithTargetClass.push(element);

    // recursive call
    if(element.children){
         traverse(element, targetClassName);
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

```
    // recursive call - updated
    if(element.children){
         for(var child in element.children)
             traverse(element.children[child], targetClassName);
    }
```

Comment: `traverse(element)` That isn't what you want.

Comment: To full traverse the DOM you need to do a pre-order traversal of the tree.

Comment: You're recursively calling `traverse()` on the same element (instead of its children), infinitely.

Comment: Also, you'll want to do some sort of regex on `className`, otherwise you'll miss elements that have both `myTarget` and another class.

Comment: @PaulRoub can you suggest something?

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Comment: Try a `for(k in element.children) traverse(element.children[k], targetClassName);` and for your comparison try `if(currentClass.indexOf(targetClassName)!=-1)`

Comment: @user4145792 for comparison, it wouldn't work if the class was a substring of another class like "container" and "sub-container". but good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Good point. You'd have to do a regular expression to check all the right cases.

Comment: Maybe splitting on space and checking that way would work, but regex seems less code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your recursive call to traverse() passes the same element that was initially passed in, so it's just doing the exact same thing over and over until the stack overflows (hey!). You need to call traverse for each of the children of element rather than passing element back in.

Comment: First to notice the big error (and write it in an answer)

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelector`. This is not `getElementsByClassName()`, nor a library. ;)

```
document.querySelector('.myTarget')
```

Comment: Perhaps, but technically fulfills the requirements.

Comment: @Vohuman , I mean that in the sense of show code for traversing the DOM rather that using a built in method or library.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account elements with multiple classes, and starting with `body`:

```js
  var targetClass = 'myTarget';
  var elementsWithTargetClass = []; // store in array
  var re = new RegExp("\\b" + targetClass + "\\b");
  
  traverse(document.body);
  
  for ( var j = 0; j < elementsWithTargetClass.length; ++j )
    elementsWithTargetClass[j].style.fontWeight = "bold";
  
  function traverse(element, targetClassName){
      // get class of current element
      var currentClass = element.className;
  
      if (currentClass.match(re))
      // add to array if class matches
    //  if(currentClass.trim() === targetClassName)
          elementsWithTargetClass.push(element);
  
      // recursive call
      if(element.children){
        for ( var i = 0; i < element.children.length; ++i )
           traverse(element.children[i]);
      }
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="myTarget">this</li>
    <li class="myTarget andAnotherClass">also this</li>
    <li>not this</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use classList?

Comment: @Scimonster Not available in older browsers (where "older" even includes IE 9).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting into to many recursions which makes the call stack grow to high. Try chaning your recursive function into a loop. This should not give you any problems.

Comment: Wrong.  The call stack is big enough that stack overflows are usually a result of user error.

Answer (score 1):

```
var root = document.documentElement;
var targetClass = 'myTarget';
var elementsWithTargetClass = []; // store in array
pre_order(root);

function pre_order(node) {
  if(node.className == targetClass) 
    elementsWithTargetClass.push(node);       
  for(var i=0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
    pre_order(node.childNodes[i]);
}
console.log(elementsWithTargetClass);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/__defineGetter__/tcde8ykL/4/)